# Struggling with xml - want to read any of various types of file into a dataset

Tags: xml, vb.net, dataset

I need to read in various types of xml files and parse the data. It seems that reading the files into a dataset is the way to go, but I am having trouble doing so.

I wondered if my test files are not well formed, but I downloaded an example file and schema, which also fails. All the files load into a document okay, per this test code:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
For thisFile As Integer = 0 To readFiles.Count - 1
  frmMain.UpdateInfo(readFiles.Item(thisFile), "I") ' tell the user
  Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
  doc.Load(readFiles.Item(thisFile))  ' this works
  Dim thisFileReader As System.IO.StringReader = New System.IO.StringReader(readFiles.Item(thisFile))
  ds.Clear()
  ds.ReadXml(thisFileReader, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema) ' this fails with "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
  For Each thisTable As DataTable In ds.Tables
    ' action...
  Next
Next
```

The sample file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><shiporder orderid="889923" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd"><orderperson>John Smith</orderperson><shipto><name>Ola Nordmann</name><address>Langgt 23</address><city>4000 Stavanger</city><country>Norway</country></shipto><item><title>Empire Burlesque</title><note>Special Edition</note><quantity>1</quantity><price>10.90</price></item><item><title>Hide your heart</title><quantity>1</quantity><price>9.90</price></item></shiporder>
```

(Note that I intentionally removed formatting, as the files I will be reading are similar.)

The sample schema looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
              <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Both are in the same folder for testing, though I thought the schema should not be used when I set the read mode to IgnoreSchema.

I feel sure I have missed something very simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `StreamReader` instead of `StringReader`, and try it without `XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema`.

```
Dim thisFileReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StringReader(readFiles.Item(thisFile))
ds.Clear()
ds.ReadXml(thisFileReader)
```

Comment: Huh - so much for example code from Microsoft! Thank you - that works perfectly on all my files.